# Flutter web InAppWebView height

Tags: html, flutter

I need to get the height of the `InAppWebView` and I am using the code below, for mobile it works but for web it returns 0 (because it uses an iframe I think). Can anyone help me?

```
InAppWebView(
                  initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(
                      data: '<div id="my_id">asd</div>'),
                  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                    controller
                        .evaluateJavascript(
                            source: 'document.body.scrollHeight;')
                        .then((value) {
                      print('value $value');
                    });
                  },
                ),
```